# What kind of optimization/regularization is this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus, regression

If I have a system:

$y_{n \times 1} = A_{n \times m} x_{m \times 1}$
where $n<m$ and $rank=n$

What kind of optimization/regularization am I doing if I use:

$x=\min\{\|x\|_2^2+1/2\lambda^T(y-Ax)\}$

the part $\|x\|^2_2$ looks like ridge regression with $\lambda=1$ but the remaining part is confusing. It is not the absolute deviation it is only the deviation.

EDIT: After lots of Googling and reading, I discovered that this is called the least-norm solution of the under-determined linear system.
Thanks.

Comment: how is the rank of the matrix $m$ when the $n < m$

Comment: @RHowe thanks! Fixed it. rank = n

Comment: This would be a very unusual cost function, indeed. There's nothing to prevent $y$ and $Ax$ from growing as far apart as you like to make the overall expression highly negative. Are you sure the $y-Ax$ part doesn't have magnitudes or a square in it somewhere? Also, what is $\lambda?$

Comment: $ \lambda $ is typically a scalar $\in (0,\infty)$ while I understand the tranpose for the inner product you're saying you have $ \lambda =1 $ so i would expect $ \textrm{ min } \{ \| x \|_{2}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\lambda \| y-Ax \| \}$

Comment: This looks like a Lagrangian to me.

Comment: @AdrianKeister no there is no square that is why I am confused. I think the $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix A.  My interpretation is that the deviations are scaled by the eigenvalues. I don't know what would be the benefit of this.

Comment: @Alt can you elaborate?

Comment: @RHowe no the $\lambda$ is probably the vector with the eigenvalues of A. I was saying that the art $||x||^2_2$ looks like the part $\lambda ||x||^2_2$ in ridge regression with $\lambda$ set to 1.

Comment: I'm looking at the regularization page and the nearest to it is slope 

$$  \textrm{ min } \frac{1}{2}\| y- Xb \| + \sum_{i=1}^{p} \lambda_{i} |b_{i}| $$

which isn't quite like this, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3824.pdf. But I don't know where you found this.

Comment: @RHowe can you post the link to the regularization page? Thanks